# How to find retransmitted TCP packets

Tags: c++, tcp, pcap, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to write a C++ program to scan a pcap file and filter out certain packets. I tried using winpcap to scan and filter but I can't find a way to separate retransmissions. Does anyone know how this filtering can be done?

Comment: Why not load up Wireshark?

Comment: If only :P.  Unfortunately I was tasked with writing a c++ program that does this filtering.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Winpcap : How do I filter retransmitted TCP packets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576299/winpcap-how-do-i-filter-retransmitted-tcp-packets)

Comment: [You already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576299/winpcap-how-do-i-filter-retransmitted-tcp-packets). Don't do that. If you get comments or answers that you don't understand, say so, ***there.***

Answer (score -1):

You will have to implement several TCP variables to do this.
Read section 3.2 of RFC 793.